# Can gRPC Java client send multiple requests in parallel over a long lived gRPC stream and how to manage N streams

Tags: multithreading, grpc, http2, grpc-java

I am using a 'Streaming RPC' API where the both MyRequests and MyResponse are streamed

```
service MyStreamedService {
  rpc myOperation(**stream** MyRequest) returns (**stream** MyResponse)
}
```

Here is a slightly simplified version of a class that wraps a gRPC stream;

```
public class MyStreamWrapper implements StreamObserver<MyResponse> {
  public MyStreamWrapper(ManagedChannel myChannel) {
    myStub = MyStreamedServiceGrpc.newStub(myChannel);
    // create a stream and maintain a long lived reference to the stream via StreamObserver's
    myStream = myStub.myOperation(this);
  }
  
  @Override
  public void onNext(MyResponse r) {
    // handle the response (not shown)
  }
  
  @Override
  public void onError(Throwable t) {
    // very unfortunate that there is no error code in this API !
    // throttle (not shown but if I don't throttle, eats CPU)
    // Create a new stream
    myStream = myStub.myOperation(this);
  }
  
  @Override
  public void onCompleted() {
    // server has called StreamObserver<MyRequest>.onCompleted
    // Create a new stream using the async API
    myStream = myStub.myOperation(this);
  }
  
  // Context: many threada that want to send a request asynchronously
  public void send(MyRequest r) {
    synchronized(myStream) {
      myStream.onNext(r);
    }
  }
}
```

Questions

1. Why does access to myStream need to be synchronized in the send method?  I would like to understand why I must synchronize threads that would like to send unordered requests in parallel on the same stream.  If each request is packaged in a HTTP2 DATA frame with its own stream-id then is this just unique to the Java implementation of the gRPC client?
2. What is guaranteed to have happened when a thread returns from method send?

- request is buffered in the gRPC client ... I think this must be a minimum
- request is on the wire as a HTTP2 stream frame ?
- Proxy has received the request ?
- Server has received but not processed ?
- Server has received and sent a response ?

3. Given that the client threads are synchronized to one invocation of onNext at a time, can the client overload the server or is back-pressure applied by blocking the client threads in the above send method?  I see Streams closing and errors like "INTERNAL: RST_STREAM closed stream. HTTP/2 error code: PROTOCOL_ERROR" under traffic.
4. Is it unusual to maintain and re-use myStream given that streams are cheap to create?
5. Given that a stream can only be directed to one server, am I correct in thinking that I need to add more code to the simple class above in order to create N myStream on channel creation and then round-robin the send method on each of the N myStream. Unfortunately, there is no API to determine if myStream is currently 'busy' with another RPC request. Alternatively, I could create new streams on the fly and add a sempaphore(size:N) to limit the number of threads attempting to use them.

Things I think I understand ...

- A gRPC channel is a collection of sub-channels and gRPC takes care of creating a network connection from the client via a different sub-channel to each server
- A gRPC stream connects to each server over a single sub-channel and requests are processed in order.
- A gRPC stream is based on a HTTP2 stream which is a series of frames with the same stream-id.
- I have also seen a gRPC stream described as a single gRPC call and understand that it is cheap to use a new stream for each request but in my working example above, it can also be long lived (or at least the gRPC Java client provides an object that makes it seem long lived)
- "At its core, gRPC is streaming. Unary (single request, single response) and server streaming (single request) are simply special cases for producing cleaner APIs or more optimized I/O behavior. But on-the-wire, everything looks the same as streaming." Eric Anderson's answer in [How is gRPC client streaming implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53234242/how-is-grpc-client-streaming-implemented) helped me to understand why the Unary API includes a StreamObserver on the server side.

Comment: Clarification: In the question above a "request" means an instance of my custom, POJO MyRequest. However I now see that in https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7540#section-8.1, that a HTTP/2 stream request may involve many frames HEADERS, DATA, DATA, END_STREAM and so a HTTP/2 request may be long lived, (in fact for the duration of the stream) and involve many MyRequests inside DATA frames.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Community Please feed the AI of the bot above with better training data to identify only  adequate posts for its annoying remarks ;-]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. First, HTTP/2 messages may be big, so putting an HTTP/2 frame on a wire is not atomic in general case, so multiple threads may be writing concurrently to the same network socket. Furthermore, there's flow control related buffering: if the other side of the stream is not ready to accept more messages, they need to be buffered on your side, so multiple threads that may be writing concurrently to the same buffer.
2. *"request is buffered in the gRPC client"* is the correct answer: `StreamObserver`'s methods are asynchronous, they return very quickly and the actual network communication will be performed by another thread at some point.
3. when sending messages, you should respect other side's readiness using methods from [CallStreamObserver](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/stub/CallStreamObserver.html): [isReady()](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/stub/CallStreamObserver.html#isReady--) and [setOnReadyHandler(...)](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/stub/CallStreamObserver.html#setOnReadyHandler-java.lang.Runnable-) (you can always cast your outbound `StreamObserver` to a `CallStreamObserver`). If you ignore other side's readiness, gRPC will buffer messages in its internal buffer until the other side is ready. This may lead to excessive memory usage in some cases, though, due to the buffering described in point 1.
   BTW: you may want to look at the official [copyWithFlowControl()](https://javadoc.io/doc/io.grpc/grpc-all/1.40.0/io/grpc/stub/StreamObservers.html#copyWithFlowControl-java.util.Iterator-io.grpc.stub.CallStreamObserver-) helper methods and my own [DispatchingOnReadyHandler](https://javadoc.io/doc/pl.morgwai.base/grpc-utils/latest/pl/morgwai/base/grpc/utils/DispatchingOnReadyHandler.html) class.
4. I guess your intention is to always have an RPC open: if so, your code seems fine. However the question is whether you should be using a single bi-di call vs. multiple unary: If server processing of 1 request message is not tightly related to the processing of others (ie: server does not need to constantly maintain a single, in-memory state related to all request messages), then unary calls will be better for at least 2 reasons:
   4.1. no synchronization as described in point 1 will be necessary.
   4.2. you will take better use of server load-balancing.
   Under normal circumstances an overhead for starting a new unary RPC is small as it will open a new stream on an *existing* HTTP/2 connection.
   If however server-side processing of some request message may be related to some other previous request messages, then indeed you do need client side streaming. You should however try to close and renew the RPC whenever possible to allow servers to balance the traffic.
5. If your client runs as a part of some server app, then `grpclb` policy is the most common load-balancing choice: it will maintain a collection of multiple HTTP/2 connections to several available backends, each connection possibly having multiple HTTP/2 streams (HTTP/2 streams correspond 1-1 with gRPC Streams). Furthermore, grpclb  will actively probe these connections to verify if they are healthy and also automatically reissue the DNS query (or whatever other name resolution service, if you use custom `NameResolver`) to see if any new backends were added when needed. Remember to include `grpc-grpclb` runtime dependency if you want to use it. See note at the bottom of the answer for more info on loadbalancing and name resolution in server app to server app case.
   If your client runs on android, then `grpclb` is not available normally (most android devices lack capabilities to run a background load balancer and even if possible it would drain device's battery quite fast), but your connections will usually go through some load-balancer standing in front of the backend servers. In such case each new RPC will usually go to the least occupied backend.
   However since you seem to be maintaining just 1 long-living call, all your request messages will be going to the same backend until the call is "renewed": that's why I suggested using unary calls if possible in the previous point. This is waaay simpler than implementing your own load-balancing, so if only possible it should be preferred.

A clarification regarding *"things I understand"* part: "sub-channels" are most usually basically HTTP/2 connections: a channel is a collection of possibly multiple HTTP/2 connections (depending on client capabilities: see point 5) to multiple backends (depending on the server configuration of course) and each connections can have multiple independent streams (1 HTTP/2 stream per 1 gRPC call).

Few notes on load balancing and name resolution in case of a server app to server app gRPCs:

- the simplest and most common way for the client side to find available backends is via a DNS resolution. More complex mechanisms include things like [xDS](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-docs/xds_protocol#xds-protocol) or Consul or custom `NameResolver`s.
- In particular, when deploying both backend and client server apps in the same k8s cluster, the most common way is to deploy the backends as a headless service, so that all backend pods can be obtained by the clients via an in-cluster DNS query about `<backed-service-name>.<k8s-namespace>.svc.cluster.local`. For example `.forTarget("myGrpcBackendService.default.svc.cluster.local:6000")`.
- By default, clients using `grpclb` will try to keep their set of connections to backends as long as possible, so even if RPCs are short-living, the underlying connections will stick to the same set of backends. To enforce periodical rebalancing, servers may set maximum connection lifetime using methods from [NettyServerBuilder](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/netty/NettyChannelBuilder.html): [maxConnectionAge(...)](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/netty/NettyServerBuilder.html#maxConnectionAge-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-), [maxConnectionAgeGrace(...)](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/netty/NettyServerBuilder.html#maxConnectionAgeGrace-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) and [maxConnectionIdle(...)](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/netty/NettyServerBuilder.html#maxConnectionIdle-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-).

Comment: Fantastic answer - many thanks.

Re:1-2. Makes sense, am now looking for the answer to  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54711882/how-to-control-the-write-buffer-size-in-grpc-or-how-to-handle-slow-stream-read)

Re:3. Great tip.  Given that I am maintaining a pool of N streams (aka N RPCs) per channel, I have been looking for a way for my N-stream LB algorithm to choose a 'healthy' stream.

Re:5 I have set ManagedChannelBuilder .defaultLoadBalancingPolicy("round_robin") because the Java docs say that the default policy is "pick_first"

Comment: Re:4 Yes I always want to have an RPC open.  I have more gRPC servers than gRPC clients so this is a Linux server-to-server scenario.  I think I need to use the streaming API because, although many of MyRequest POJOs sent on the same stream are not related, some of them are related and in that case ordering needs to be maintained.  I am aware that my long lived streams should be closed periodically to allow for scaling of the server side. PS I tried to mark your answer as the accepted answer to the question but nothing happens.

Comment: @DiarmuidLeonard if it's server2server then you definitely should be using `grpclb` LB policy. Just make sure to include `grpc-grpclb` in your runtime dependencies before doing so: it actively probes connections if they are healthy and periodically reissues the DNS query to see if new backends were added (if your servers are deployed on k8s as a headless service, then grpclb on the client side will automatically add any newly created backend pods to its list). Again, this will work much better if you use short-lived RPCs, as a long-lived cannot be moved to another backend.

Comment: @DiarmuidLeonard regarding related request objects: yes this sounds as a good justification. The only improvement that comes to my mind in such case is to close the RPC if it happens that you know at some point that no new request will be related to any previous one. BTW: these are not POJOs anymore as they are protocol-buffers ;-)

Comment: @DiarmuidLeonard is it the case maybe that a given request may be related to another request sent only from the same thread? if so, then it would be probably easier and more optimal if every of your threads had its own RPC.

Comment: @DiarmuidLeonard yeah, `grpclb` cannot be the default as its availability depends on inclusion of `grpc-grpclb` runtime dependency. Sorry for confusion: my bad.

Comment: @DiarmuidLeonard regarding buffer size: if you use `isReady()` and `setOnReadyHandler()` then you don't need to worry about your buffer size. I have no idea how to control it as I always use the these methods. Btw: you may want to look at [the official copyWithFlowControl() helper methods](https://javadoc.io/doc/io.grpc/grpc-all/1.40.0/io/grpc/stub/StreamObservers.html#copyWithFlowControl-java.util.Iterator-io.grpc.stub.CallStreamObserver-) and my own [DispatchingOnReadyHandler](https://javadoc.io/doc/pl.morgwai.base/grpc-utils/latest/pl/morgwai/base/grpc/utils/DispatchingOnReadyHandler.html)

Comment: @DiarmuidLeonard I've added some notes about load-balancing and name resolution that may be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that all the answers are available in the HTTP/2 spec https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7540# which is very readable.

1. Answered by [Eric Anderson](https://groups.google.com/g/grpc-io/c/tK8qyVn9rm4?pli=1) "Note that the object is not thread-safe, so if you call methods on it from multiple threads simultaneously you should do your own locking/synchronization".  Doesn't really explain why, I guess that the Unary API did not need to be synchronized so they didn't synchronize for the Streaming API
2. The application request is at least in a buffer ready to put on the wire in a HTTP DATA frame.  The thread is not blocked waiting for any confirmation that it has been received. DATA frames are not ACK'd anyway. The application may be prevented from sending the data due to HTTP2 Flow Control to prevent overloading the far end but it seems unlikely that even in this case, the thread would be blocked.
3. As per above, Flow Control is described at https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7540#section-6.9.  The server grants permission to the client to send a number of bytes and the client must stop when the allocation has been used.
4. No, not unusual.  [Here](https://groups.google.com/g/grpc-io/c/tK8qyVn9rm4?pli=1), Eric Anderson says "for fully-asynchronous processing we would expect you to start any I/O on the current thread and then call methods on StreamObserver from some other thread once the I/O completes.". Duplicate of [Java gRPC server for long-lived streams effective implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64066930/java-grpc-server-for-long-lived-streams-effective-implementation)
5. As per Eric Anderson's response above, I think it is normal to cache the stream reference and re-use it.  However, I don't know why the Java channel API does not include method int getStreamLimit() because the client needs to know many streams it is allowed to use as per the SETTINGS_MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS value in the HTTP2 SETTINGS message exchanged during creating of the channel.

General comment:
I found the gRPC documentation difficult to understand until I realized that most of the deeper questions can be answered by studying HTTP2
e.g.
a HTTP2 Request does not correspond 1:1 with the application request object in the proto IDL.  Keypoint: HTTP2 Request continues for the duration of the stream and can carry many application request objects.